# Extract both href and link using css selectors in scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm writing a spider to extract the text and corresponding hyperlink from a web page. Here's my spider code:

```
import scrapy

class GeneralElection2019Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'general_election_2019'
    allowed_domains = ['https://eci.gov.in/']
    start_urls = ['https://eci.gov.in/files/category/1359-general-election-2019/']

    def parse(self, response):
        print(f'\nProcessing: {response.url}\n')
        #data = response.css('.ipsType_break.ipsContained a::attr(href)').extract() # Hyperlink
        data = response.css('.ipsType_break.ipsContained a::attr(title)').extract() # Text
        for row in data:
            print(f'{row}\n')
```

I can get either the text or hyperlink but I want both at the same time.

Comment: you should explode this to 2 steps: 1. get `<a>` element, 2. extract data from it.  [Here](https://github.com/scrapy/quotesbot/blob/master/quotesbot/spiders/toscrape-css.py#L12-L17) is example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this

```
import scrapy
    class GeneralElection2019Spider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = 'general_election_2019'
        allowed_domains = ['eci.gov.in']
        start_urls = ['https://eci.gov.in/files/category/1359-general-election-2019/']
    
        def parse(self, response):
            print(f'\nProcessing: {response.url}\n')
            for data in response.css('li.ipsDataItem'):
                text = data.css('span.ipsType_break.ipsContained a::attr(title)').get()
                text2 = data.css('span.ipsType_break.ipsContained a::text').get()
                link = data.css('span.ipsType_break.ipsContained a::attr(href)').get()
                print(text)
                print(text2)
                print(link)
```

Comment: I noticed that before the loop I get a lot of messages like "DEBUG: Rule at line 1 without any user agent to enforce it on." What is the reason for this? Can this be fixed?

Comment: It's DEBUG , not error. You can set headers in custom_settings > custom_settings = {
        'SOME_SETTING': 'some value',
    }https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html